# Can you please explain the Gradient Descent?

Tags: taylor-expansion, vector-analysis, gradient-descent

I was looking at the gradient descent algorithm. Then I am confused about the second line on  below. The instructor mentioned something related to the Taylor series expansion. I am not sure how the first line related to the second line in terms of the 'gradient' operator. Any ideas?

$\bigtriangleup f= f(w(1))-f(w(0)),$  where $w(1)=w(0)+\eta \vec{v}$

$=\eta \triangledown f(w(0))^T \vec{v} +O(\eta^2)$

$\geq-\eta||\triangledown f(w(0))||$

[This is the original slide in case you are interested.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1IRe.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [multivariate Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables). Expanding about $w_0$, we get:
$$
f(x)=f(w_0)+(x-w_0)^T\nabla f(w_0) + O(||x-w_0||_2^2)
$$
So then evaluating the function at $w_0+\eta\hat{v}$, for some unit vector $\hat{v}$, gives:
\begin{align}
f(w_0+\eta\hat{v})
&=f(w_0)+(\eta\hat{v})^T\nabla f(w_0)+O(||\eta\hat{v}||_2^2)\\
&=f(w_0)+\eta\nabla f(w_0)^T\hat{v}+O(\eta^2)
\end{align}
Thus, the difference is given by:
$$ \Delta f = f(w_0+\eta\hat{v})-f(w_0)= \eta\nabla f(w_0)^T\hat{v}+O(\eta^2) $$
as required.

As for the third line, use the fact that $\hat{v}$ is a unit vector:
$$
\Delta f = \eta\,||\nabla f(w_0)||_2 \,\underbrace{||\hat{v}||_2}_1\underbrace{\cos(\theta_{[\hat{v},\nabla f(w_0)]})}_{\geq -1} \geq -\eta ||\nabla f(w_0)||_2 
$$

Comment: this makes sense! it took a minute for me to see that you used the cosine formula for the dot product, but i get it now. thanks!